# How to import time column from snowflake to jupyter notebook dataframe?

Tags: python, jupyter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to import data from snowflake to Jupyter. In the dataset I have a time column which is derived from timestamp values.

Every time I try to import the data, Jupyter says the process failed and below is the error message.

How should I get around this issue?

```
ERROR:snowflake.connector.converter:Failed to convert: field T: TIME::76493.000000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/converter.py", line 88, in to_python
    type_name=type_name))
AttributeError: 'SnowflakeConverter' object has no attribute '_TIME_to_python'
ERROR:snowflake.connector.cursor:failed to convert row to python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 658, in __row_to_python
    res += (self._connection.converter.to_python(col_desc, col),)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/converter.py", line 88, in to_python
    type_name=type_name))
AttributeError: 'SnowflakeConverter' object has no attribute '_TIME_to_python'
ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the Python Connector version? The error indicates TIME data type is not supported by Python Connector. TIME data type has been supported since v1.0.6. As of today, the latest version is 1.2.8:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/snowflake-connector-python/

Here is an example of TIME data type in Jupyter notebook:
https://gist.github.com/smtakeda/e401c80d71f2da4aa7452d238c5ccffa

Comment: the link to the example does not work, does git host live notebooks, or would it be possible to download it locally?